# Word cloud: combine variations of the same word

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am trying to create a word cloud in python (wordcloud) and I see a bunch of variations of the same root word. For example: "create, creativity, creation, creating" etc. Is there a way for them to be combined as a single word/idea?

Comment: Look up "stemming".

Comment: There's several ways this could be accomplished, but you haven't given enough detail about your input data to know how best to help you. Please provide a [mcve] including input, output, and what you've tried so far